# Function that returns visibility

Tags: android

I was writing a function that is returning a visibility - but I correctly get:

> Must be one of: View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE less...

for this code:

```
private int getVisibilityForGlobalAndLocal(final boolean global, final boolean local) {
   if (global) {
       return View.GONE;
   }                
   return local ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
}
```

when using like this:

```
 view.setVisibility(getVisibilityForGlobalAndLocal(true,false));
```

Unfortunately @Visibility annotation is hidden in View:

```
/** @hide */
@IntDef({VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, GONE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Visibility {}
```

Now I can just copy this part ( works ) but it feels bad. Is there a more elegant solution I am missing here? Should I file this as a bug?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer on what's happening and where you're getting a bug?  You code looks perfectly legal to me.  As for a Visibility interface-  there is no such thing.  The 3 visibilities are constants and are treated as ints throughout the framework.

Comment: is that a lint error?

Comment: Not sure if this is elegant, but you can add this comment just above the call to view.setVisibility to supress the warning:  //noinspection ResourceType

Answer (score 5):

It would definitely be nice to be able to use the @Visibility annotation but it looks like we can't at the moment.

In the meantime you can add the @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") annotation above the method in which you call setVisibility to suppress the lint error

```
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
public void myMethod()
{
    view.setVisibility(getVisibilityForGlobalAndLocal(true,false));
}
```

Comment: thanks - upvoted - but I really hate to disable this - I think I then prefer copying the annotation

Comment: One odd thing I have seen. I did create my own Visibility annotation that is exactly the same as in android.view.View, however lint fails with:

error: Must be one of: 0, 4, 8 [WrongConstant]
                   <my_view>.setCenterTextVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: If you want to use this in a bigger method which does more stuff, you can add the comment `//noinspection ResourceType`  just above the line where the `view.setVisibility(getVisibilityForGlobalAndLocal(true,false));`. This way you don't suppress warning for the whole method :)